# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7 1 3 4 1 7' . Hackerrank question showing error

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, int

'''

```
listSize=int(input())
arrayList=list()
dist=listSize
k=int
i=int
for i in range(1,listSize):
    arrayNo=int(input())
    arrayList.append(arrayNo)
for i in range(1,listSize):
    k=i+1
    for k in range(1,listSize):
        if(arraylist[i]==arrayList[k]&k-i<dist):
            dist=k-i
        k+=1
    i+=1
print(dist)
```

'''

I'm getting an error
Main que is: Print out the minimum difference of indices having same value element value
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "Solution.py", line 7, in <module>

    arrayNo=int(input())

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7 1 3 4 1 7'
```

Comment: int() is expecting a number, the problem is that you give it multiple numbers with spaces, so it's understood as string

Answer (score 1):

Your argument to `int()` is a string that contains multiple "integers" separated by spaces. Look at documentation for the `split()` method on strings to split your input into the pieces you want, then apply int() on them.